# Error while Programmatically adding chart control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I am trying to programmatic-ally add a Chart in WPF and then add a Bar graph to it, however I get an error which states that chart.cs or DataPointSeries.cs is missing. I have added the Toolkit dll. Also if I remove the Bar1.Itemsource code the chart works but with no graph but with a legend. Any ideas?

```
Chart Ch1 = new Chart();


BarSeries Bar1 = new BarSeries();
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tom", 2220));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Jim", 23330));

Bar1.ItemsSource = valueList;

Bar1.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
Bar1.IndependentValuePath = "Value";   


Ch1.Name = "BarChart";
Ch1.Series.Add(Bar1);

Grid Backgrid = new Grid();
Backgrid.Children.Add(Ch1);
```

Comment: Have you also included a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll`?

Answer (score 0):

Bar1.DependentValuePath = "Value";
instead of:
Bar1.IndependentValuePath = "Value";

Comment: Hi Khaled, I am not able to test this as I do not use WPF anymore, so if you could provide more details I could mark this as the right answer.